# Pandas not exporting all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I have googled my problem but did not get any help.

**Problem Statement:**
When I save final CSV using `df.to_csv()` after performing `cumsum()` on one of the column `amount`, My CSV only showing one column `amount` but I want all the columns in my final CSV.

**Sample Data:**

```
*------------------------------------------------*
|effective_date | account_id | currency | amount |
*------------------------------------------------*
|   12/26/19          1        USD         50    |
|   12/27/19          1        USD         70    |
|   11/06/19          2        USD         90    |
|   11/07/19          2        USD         30    |
*------------------------------------------------*
```

My Code using Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('payments.csv', index_col=0)

df['effective_when'] = pd.to_datetime(df['effective_when'])

df = df.groupby(['account_id', 'currency', 'effective_date']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()

df.to_csv ('cumulativePayments.csv')
```

**Current Result**:

```
*------*
|amount|
*------*
| 50   |
| 120  |
| 90   |
| 120  |
*------*
```

**Expected Result:**

```
*------------------------------------------------*
|effective_date | account_id | currency | amount |
*------------------------------------------------*
|   12/26/19          1       USD          50    |
|   12/27/19          1       USD          120   |
|   11/06/19          2       USD          90    |
|   11/07/19          2       USD          120   |
*------------------------------------------------*
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can split code to create `DataFrame` with aggregation `sum` and then reaasign `amount` columns filled by cumulative sums:

```
df = pd.read_csv('payments.csv', index_col=0)

df['effective_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['effective_date'])

df = df.groupby(['account_id', 'currency', 'effective_date'], as_index=False).sum()
df['amount'] = df.groupby('account_id')['amount'].cumsum()
print (df)
   account_id currency effective_date  amount
0           1      USD     2019-12-26      50
1           1      USD     2019-12-27     120
2           2      USD     2019-11-06      90
3           2      USD     2019-11-07     120

df.to_csv('cumulativePayments.csv')
```

Another idea should be convert first column to datetimes and for write to file remove default index values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('payments.csv', parse_dates=[0])

df = df.groupby(['account_id', 'currency', 'effective_date'], as_index=False).sum()
df['amount'] = df.groupby('account_id')['amount'].cumsum()

df.to_csv('cumulativePayments.csv', index=False)
```